# Problem with assembly resolve in xaml (workflow) after update to .NET Framework 4.8

Tags: xaml, workflow, appfabric

I have an old project with workflow (Appfabric) files in xaml and that project was targeting framework 4.0. We needed to update framework version so we changed the framework to 4.8 and suddenly some of our xaml files stop working.

I could see that there had been no change in the files but still we got errors saying that it can not load some of our custom activity because it could not find files that were in the project.

When looking at the imports it said that Namespace [Namespace.Name] cannot be resolved for those namespace where our custom activity was.
The code for the activity had not change and it was working but somehow the xaml file could not resolve it any more.

The only thing we did was to change the target framework to 4.8 for the project.

I am stuck and wounder if anyone else has had the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

If this is still an issue:

1. Can you please confirm that the error is coming from AppFabric and
2. post the full error message

Answer (score 0):

The same

Error       Assembly '' can not be resolved.  Please add a reference to this assembly in the project that is being built.   [Project]   [Path].xaml